# Small doubts partitions in Ubuntu, please help

Tags: installation, partitioning, 64-bit, hibernate, swap

I have two small questions:

- I want to erase "Windows 7 - 64-bit", by using Ubuntu 10.11 on the entire hard drive, but I don't want to delete my `/home/` dir, so is it necessary to delete all partitions or just delete `C:`
- Furthermore i want to create a swap partition area (my PC has 8GB of ram), so is it necessary to have the same ram in swap, or is 4GB of ram okay? I want to hibernate.

Greetings and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. What? Does your W7 have a /home partition that you want to keep? As a general advice, delete the partitions you don't need, and keep those you do.
2. With 8GB of RAM, you most probably don't need a swap partition, unless you plan on using VMs a lot. Anyway, swap can be less then RAM.

Answer (score 1):

You will need 9Gb swap if you desire hibernation etc. If you do not then you can easily get away with no swap at all :)

When you reinstall, mark the /home partition for use and mounting AS /home (/home cannot be NTFS based as it causes problems) but mark it to NOT be formatted and it will be added appropriately to /etc/fstab